# React/Redux: Why blog app is not removing the items?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a simple blog app using react and redux, right now only two functionalities are present in the app -> rendering and deleting blogs. Rendering is working fine but not the delete one.

Most likely, the issue will be in the reducer of my application. Please Suggest.
Here's my whole code.

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-75tjd?file=/src/index.js

ACTION

```
import { DELETE_BLOGS, GET_BLOGS } from "./actionTypes";

// for rendering list of blogs
export const getBlog = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_BLOGS,
  };
};

// for deleting the blogs
export const deleteBlogs = (id) => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_BLOGS,
    id,
  };
};
```

REDUCER

```
import { DELETE_BLOGS, GET_BLOGS } from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  blogs: [
    { id: 1, title: "First Blog", content: "A new blog" },
    { id: 2, title: "Second Blog", content: "Just another Blog" },
  ],
};

const blogReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.types) {
    case GET_BLOGS:
      return {
        ...state, // a copy of state
      };
    case DELETE_BLOGS:
      return {
        ...state,
        blogs: state.filter((blog) => blog.id !== action.id),
      };
    default:
      return state; // original state
  }
};

export default blogReducer;
```

COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { deleteBlogs } from "../actions/blogActions";

class AllBlogs extends Component {
  removeBlogs = (id) => {
    console.log("removeBlogs function is running with id", id);
    this.props.deleteBlogs(id); // delete action
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.blogs.map((blog) => (
          <div key={blog.id}>
            <h3>{blog.title}</h3>
            <p>{blog.content}</p>
            <button onClick={() => this.removeBlogs(blog.id)}>delete</button>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  blogs: state.blogs,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteBlogs })(AllBlogs);
```

Comment: You've done state.filter, not state.blogs.filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ISSUE**

You were sending action key `type` and receiving as `action.types` in reducer

**SOLUTION**

```
const blogReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) { // change `types` to `type`
    case DELETE_BLOGS:
      return {
        ...state,
        blogs: state.blogs.filter((blog) => blog.id !== action.id)
      };
    default:
      return state; // original state
  }
};
```

Comment: didn't work :(  here's the link to the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-75tjd?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @YashMarmat updated my answer please check